# Python + Wand.Image - saving output images to AWS with sequential pagenumber.jpg names

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, wand

I am working on a script that would Convert a PDF from the internet (without saving it to disk) to a series of jpegs, then save the JPGs to AWS s3.

Unfortunately, the code below only saves the first page of the PDF as JPG to AWS.  Any ideas on how I can modify it to save images to AWS with sequential file names?

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from wand.image import Image
from io import BytesIO
import boto3
    s3 = boto3.client(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id='mykey',
        aws_secret_access_key='mykey'
    )

    bucket_name = 'testbucketAWS323'
    #location on disk

    #file prefix
test_id = 'example'
f = urlopen("https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/converted1jpgs/example.pdf")
bytes_io_file = BytesIO()
with Image(file=f) as img:
    print('pages = ', len(img.sequence))
    with img.convert('png') as converted:
        bytes_io_file = BytesIO(converted.make_blob('jpeg'))
      #code below should take 'converted' object, and save it to AWS as jpg. 
        s3.upload_fileobj(bytes_io_file, bucket_name, "assssd.jpg")
        print 'done'
```

Comment: looking at this... looks like the issue may be with me using bytes_io_file ...  something about this command is only grabbing first image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just enumerate over the document pages (`wand.image.Image.sequence`) to get the page number & resource. With the page resource copied to a new instance of `Image`, export blob directly, and don't worry about intermediate conversions.

```py
from urllib2 import urlopen
from wand.image import Image
from io import BytesIO
import boto3

# ....

url = 'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/converted1jpgs/example.pdf'
resource = urlopen(url)
with Image(file=resource) as document:
    for page_number, page in enumerate(document.sequence):
        with Image(page) as img:
            bytes_io_file = BytesIO(img.make_blob('JPEG'))
            filename = 'output_{0}.jpg'.format(page_number)
            s3.upload_fileobj(bytes_io_file, bucket_name, filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using the [upload_fileobj](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj) method on converted?

Comment: thanks for putting me on the right track.  looks like i needed to make 'converted' a proper object first.  now i am running into a different issue.   quetions updated.